# Why use c to create a vector when a colon does the same?

Tags: r

I have just started learning R from the O'Reilly book "Learning R". It says that colon is used to create a sequence of numbers, while c function is used to concatenate it into a vector. I tried the following in R Studio:

```
a = 1:5
```

and the following:

```
a = c(1:5)
```

And they both seemed to have the same effect. Even statements like the ones below had the same effect:

```
a = 1:5 + 1:5
a = c(1:5 + 1:5)
```

I tried checking their datatype using class() and typeof() and they are the same too. Maybe I do not understand the importance as I have just started, but can someone please explain why c function needs to be used instead of just creating a sequence?
Thank you.

Comment: A colon will give you a sequential vector of numbers, whereas you can place any series of a single class into a vector with `c()` (for example `c(1, 4, 3, 2, 5)` or (`c("a", "c", "e")`))

Comment: Ah ok. So I can use colon for numbers and "c" for other datatypes. Or just use "c" everywhere for consistency. Thanks!

Comment: The colon is very handy to make a sequential list of numbers. FYI `letters` can be used similarly for vectors of sequential letters.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know that! Coming from Python, all of this looks so natural! Thank you.

Comment: It's natural ... until it isn't. For instance, `c(1,2,3)` is not the same as `1:3`: the former is `numeric` (float), the latter is `integer`. Though R is fairly liberal with coercing them around as needed, that does not always perfectly suit one's needs. (This was not perfectly within your question, but I wanted to add it to the conversation.)

Comment: Wow ok, Didnt expect that. Thank you. Adding it to my notes!